# How to provide multiple config values to httr::GET config argument

Tags: r, azure-storage, httr

For Azure Blob storage I need to provide [authentication values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx), plus an additional header called `x-ms-date`.

### Setup

```
library(httr)
container<-"https://preconstuff.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list"
sak<-"Q8HvUVJLBJK+wkrIEG6LlsfFo19iDjneTwJxX/KXSnUCtTjgyyhYnH/5azeqa1bluGD94EcPcSRyBy2W2A/fHQ=="
login<-authenticate(user = "preconstuff",password = sak)
extras<-add_headers(`x-ms-date`=Sys.time())
```

### Problem

If I run `content(GET(container,config = login ))` it says the date header isn't provided.

In terms of using the objects `login` and `extras` together, putting them as a list doesn't seem to work.

If I change `extras` to include the authentication component (taking the `userpwd` header construction from the `authenticate` function)

```
extras<-add_headers(httpauth =1, userpwd = paste0("preconstuff:", sak), 
                    `x-ms-date`=as.character(Sys.time()))
```

Then run `content(GET(container,config = extras ))`, I get "ResourceNotFound" suggesting it's not recognising my credentials.

**How to correctly pass the multiple values in?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All unnamed parameters passed to `GET()` are passed through to `config`. This means you you can do

```
content( GET(container, login, extras) )
```

Alternatively, he config options are basically just lists, you can use `c()` to combine bits. For example

```
content( GET(container, config = c(login, extras)) )
```

Comment: I'll check it out - but the thing is a reproducible example? No IP restrictions or anything so the key should work for anyone?

Comment: Still - much closer. I suspect the remaining issue is that the datetime needs to be passed in a correct format. Needs to look like: `x-ms-date:Sun, 20 Sep 2009 20:36:40 GMT`. Still, just formatting - will mark your answer as correct when I can.

Comment: @StephLocke Actually, I think the problem is the authentication. By default the httr `authenticate()` function uses "basic" authentication. From the link to the docs you provided, that is not supported by Azure. You need to use "SharedKey" or "SharedKeyLite." Reading `?authenticate`, those to not appear to be supported by `rCurl` so you may need to provide your own implementation of that authentication method.

Comment: Now that I've got the date formatting correctly, Basic auth is indeed the next error

Comment: Or just `GET(container, login, extras)`